# Connect SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO with CPANEL Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have MS SQL SERVER MS on my pc which I want to connect with the laravel project in Cpanel I have created two rules in the firewall for the port forwarding and I have given the port 1433 for MS SQL now when I go to port checker it shows the port is available but when I give the details to laravel .env file it is showing this error: "[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ST5.jpg
"
How will I be able to fix this issue????

any help will be highly appreciated

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
// Add a coma character after each filename, using a case insensitive replace.
$commaSeparatedFilenames = str_ireplace('.dbf', '.dbf,', $file);
// Then create an array containing each filename.
$filenamesArray = explode(',', $commaSeparatedFilenames);
```